# Wordpress hide widgets section from Customizer

Tags: wordpress, widget

So I'm trying to get rid of these widgets showing up in the Customizer to keep the customizer simple.

I could remove the default site tagline and title with this code:

```
$wp_customize->remove_section( 'title_tagline' );
$wp_customize->remove_section( 'static_front_page' );
```

Any ideas about how to remove widgets using a similar code?

Answer (score 4):

I found this

```
  $wp_customize->remove_panel('widgets');
```

It's work for me.